# Angular 5: Circular dependency detected between models

Tags: angular, model, warnings, circular-dependency

I'm stuck for few days with this error, and I don't know how to solve it.

I have 2 models in my app : `User` and `Team`.

user.ts :

```
import { Team } from './team';

export class User {

id: string = null;
name: string = null;
email: string = null;
settings: any = {};

team: Team = null;

constructor(json?: Object){
    var defaultSettings = {};

    if(json){
        this.id = json['id'] || null;
        this.name = json['name'] || null;
        this.email = json['email'] || null;
        this.settings = json['settings'] || {};

        this.team = new Team(json['team']) || null;
    }
}

getSettings(){
    return  Object.assign(this.team.settings, this.settings);
}
```

team.ts

```
import { User } from './user';

export class Team {

id: string = null;
name: string = null;
settings: any = {};

users: User[] = [];

constructor(json?: any){
    if(json){
        this.id = json['id'] || null;
        this.name = json['name'] || null;
        this.settings = json['settings'] || {};

        if(json['users']) json['users'].forEach(user => this.users.push(new User(user)));
    }
}
```

}

When the user is logged in, I got his infos with the team. Like that, I can do `user.getSettings()` directly from the User, and get a merged array of these settings and the Team.

In the other hand, when I show a Team, it can have some users.

But with that, I got a warning :

`WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/_models/user.ts -> src/app/_models/team.ts -> src/app/_models/user.ts`

Is it possible to keep this logic and avoid the Circular dependency warning?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The answer to your question is 'No, and you should not keep it like that'. Circular dependency means that you have wrong design and you need to fix it. That's all I can say for sure from the information you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days, I've finally created a third model **"LoggedUser"**, which extends my **"User"** model, with the **"team: Team"** property :

user.ts :

```
export class User {

    id: string = null;
    name: string = null;
    email: string = null;
    settings: any = {};

    constructor(json?: Object){
        var defaultSettings = {};

        if(json){
            this.id = json['id'] || null;
            this.name = json['name'] || null;
            this.email = json['email'] || null;
            this.settings = json['settings'] || {};
        }
    }
}
```

team.ts :

```
import { User } from './user';

export class Team {

    id: string = null;
    name: string = null;
    settings: any = {};

    users: User[] = [];

    constructor(json?: any){
        if(json){
            this.id = json['id'] || null;
            this.name = json['name'] || null;
            this.settings = json['settings'] || {};

            if(json['users']) json['users'].forEach(user => this.users.push(new User(user)));
        }
    }
}
```

loggedUser.ts :

```
import { User } from './user';
import { Team } from './team';

export class LoggedUser extends User {

    team: Team = null;

    constructor(json?: Object) {
        super(json);

        this.team = new Team(json['team']) || null;
    }    

    getSettings(){
        return  Object.assign(this.team.settings, this.settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to keep this logic and avoid the Circular dependency warning?

By Adding this to your angular-cli.json you can get rid of the warning.

```
    "defaults": {

    "build": {

        "showCircularDependencies": false 
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry, the correct answer is change the desing. As idea, why not replace in User the property Team by just a property teamId?