# Circular dependency in recursive objects (linked by calling static methods) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular6, angular7

It is possible to create tree / recursive objects in separate files and avoid `Circular dependency detected` warning using *Angular CLI* if I call methods from classes recursive?

*(Tested in angular 7)* I understand that this is a problem in dependency injection ([article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/)), but what about the objects using as constructor for data from external api or for internal purposes? And if it is not good idea anyway, how do you solve it? (I suppose the answer for this 'subquestion' is a change of model, then how should I modify my model?) I search for solution but [the closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072091/angular-5-circular-dependency-detected-between-models) did not help me apply the same approach to my situation.

I have `Emails` and `Attachments` (emails with attachments - and the entire `Email` with attachments can also be an attachment, `Attachment` is separated object with attributes and content can be `File` or `Email`, but here, for simplicity, suppose the attachment is always one `Email` or null).
Each **class has static method** for create instance from JSON object (I get JSON from API, then I will create instance of object representing API values by calling static `fromJson` method on top object):

*file: app/model/email.ts (part of code)*

```js
import { Attachment } from './attachment';

export class Email {
  // some attributes
  public attachment?: Attachment;

  public static fromJson(js: JSON): Email {
    const e = new Email();
    // fill some attributes here
    if (js['attachment']) { e.attachment = Attachment.fromJson(js['attachment']); }
    return e;
  }
}
```

*file: app/model/attachment.ts (part of code)*

```
import { Email } from './email';
export class Attachment {
  // some attributes
  public content: Email;

  public static fromJson(js: JSON): Attachment {
    const a = new Attachment();
    // fill some attributes here
    if (js['email']) { a.content = Email.fromJson(js['email']); }
    return a;
  }
}
```

Initial call is: `this.email = Email.fromJson(apiResponseForEmail);`

This situation result into *Circular dependency detected* warning after `ng build | serve`. If this is not a good example for you, you can imagine `Recipe` class for food which contains `Ingredients` with attributes such as quantity and temperature where the result of one `Recipe` is a ingredient for another recipe.

**If these classes are in one file, no warning is reported.** However, placing everything in one big file is not the best solution to me (if there is any other).

Here is a [Stackblitz with Circular dependency demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cirdepdemo) (but without warnings in console, stackblitz obviously removes warnings, you need to download this code and run from localhost to see warning).

I am interested if **it is possible to place such classes (which are called in the code recursive by static method like in the example) in separate files (files named by classes) and avoid Circular dependency detected message**?

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to get rid of circular dependency is to introduce `index.ts`

file: index.ts

```
export { Attachment } from './attachment';
export { Email } from './email';
```

file: app/model/attachment.ts (part of code)

```
import * as index_file from './index';
index_file.Attachment {
  ...
  content: index_file.Email;
}
```

file: app/model/email.ts (part of code)

```
import * as index_file from './index';
index_file.Email {
  ...
  attachment?: index_file.Attachment;
}
```

PS: please check the syntax, I'm not confident on the syntax

Comment: Ok, I checked the syntax and make some fixes. You need to export class from index if you want to import index in another file, but if it is true and this was your intention, then you get circular dependency between index and Attachment or between index and Email... If I correctly implemented it, I'm seeing the WARNING in Circular dependency detected: `src/app/model/email.ts -> src/app/model/index.ts -> src/app/model/email.ts` with this approach. I updated my question to explain what causes this recursive dependency and example in stackblitz.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi @Atiris !**

I already had this problem in a complex project with a lot of circular dependencies (**56 warnings**).
After many tries, I don't think I have found the right solution.

But I can possibly tell you how I did to solve each of the warnings.
I moved each implemented selector with a warning to the main file.
But it's not very clean.

Have you tried to use only 1 file ?
You can create a **namespace** in which you add the two classes **Email** and **Attachment**.

Here is a [Stackblitz without Circular dependency demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cirdepdemo-zcsgv9)

---

**ANSWER** :

> I am interested if it is possible to place such classes (which are
>   called in the code recursive by static method like in the example) in
>   separate files (files named by classes) and avoid Circular dependency
>   detected message?

I don't think you can make like that. This is structural issue. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your approach to the solution. Using only one file is my actual solution for now, but it's really confusing. If all classes are in one file, you do not even need a **namespace**, everything works like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/cirdepdemo-tumttz The problems starts with splitting one class per file.

Answer (score 1):

I think we all have habits coming from compiled languages. In JS files are modules. I think this is the root of the problem : these are not class files but module files.

Maybe you should use some other packing tools to merge you class files in a single module (so in a single file).

If you can put different classes in different namespaces there's a high chance that you won't have interdependent classes across these namespaces, so you can make one module per namespace. However interdependent classes should probably belong to a single namespace (=> same module => same file => need extra tools to pack)

EDIT: old question but I landed here an scratched my head to here are my two cents